# Listening for a threading Event in python

Tags: python, events, python-multithreading, pyserial

first time SO user, please excuse any etiquette errors. I'm trying to implement a multithreaded program in python and am having troubles. This is no doubt due to a lack of understanding of how threading is implemented, but hopefully you can help me figure it out.

I have a basic program that continually listens for messages on a serial port and can then print/save/process/etc them, which works fine. It basically looks like this:

```
import serial
def main():
    usb = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-A603UBRB', 57600) #open serial w\ baud rate
    while True:
        line = usb.readline()
        print(line)
```

However what I want to do is continually listen for the messages on a serial port, but not necessarily do anything with them. This should run in the background, and meanwhile in the foreground I want to have some kind of interface where the user can command the program to read/use/save these data for a while and then stop again.

So I created the following code:

```
import time
import serial
import threading

# this runs in the background constantly, reading the serial bus input
class serial_listener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, line, event):
        super(serial_listener, self).__init__()
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.line = ''
        self.usb = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-A603UBRB', 57600)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.line = self.usb.readline()
            self.event.set()
            self.event.clear()
            time.sleep(0.01)

# this lets the user command the software to record several values from serial
class record_data(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(record_data, self).__init__()
        self.line = ''
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.ser = serial_listener(self.line,self.event)
        self.ser.start() #run thread

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            user_input = raw_input('Record data: ')
            if user_input == 'r':
                event_counter = 0
                while(event_counter < 16):
                    self.event.wait()
                    print(self.line)
                    event_counter += 1

# this is going to be the mother function
def main():
    dat = record_data()
    dat.start()

# this makes the code behave like C code.    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It compiles and runs, but when I order the program to record by typing r into the CLI, nothing happens. It doesn't seem to be receiving any events.

Any clues how to make this work? Workarounds are also fine, the only thing is that I can't constantly open and close the serial interface, it has to remain open the whole time, or else the device stops working until un/replugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using multiple threads, I would suggest using multiple processes. When you use threads, you have to think about the global interpreter lock. So you either listen to events or do something in your main thread. Both at the same time will not work.

When using multiple processes I would then use a queue to forward the events from your watchdog that you would like to handle. Or you could code your own event handler. [Here](http://rnovitsky.blogspot.co.il/2012/10/python-event-listener-multiprocessing.html?_sm_au_=iVVjSQTkkMPM1DWN) you can find an example for multiprocess event handlers

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was unable to understand it at the time, and ended up resorting to simply creating two separate python scripts that communicate via a cache on disk. Now months later I came back to the issue and decided to rebuild my GUI in pyqt instead of tkinter. And with PyQT's QThread class it ended up being really easy for me to do what I wanted, a lot easier than with the threading module.